# Почему функция возвращает NaN? (необходимо вернуть сумму элементов массива)

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не понимаю почему NaN видит, массив то считает

Comment: оформите вопрос кодом пожайлуйста, а не скрином.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выходите за пределы массива. Следует изменить условие завершения цикла на:

```
i < arr.length
```

Comment: Спасибо
Да да, сам заметил, что lengh -1 нужно писать.